# Missed Call in Lync/Skype database?

Tags: skype, lync, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

In our company, we use Lync/Skype for Business. In the database, is there a way to know whether a call is missed?

For example, a customer called the support number, but for certain reason, the call is not pickup, is there a way to find this call info by query Lync/Sfb database?

Or, Lync/SfB will not log info in this case?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the "Call" did you refer here to a PSTN call? If thats a simple VOIP call then a so called peer2peer call might happen here which didn´t involved the Skype for Business (=SfB) / Lync server as this is done between both SfB clients without the server.

I think a good step might be to check whats currently possible with the build in Monitoring Reports in Skype for Business Server (see [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj204989.aspx) as starting point).